# Adding Spacing to Bootstrap List

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, html-lists

I am very new to html and twitter bootstrap but guessing that there is a very simple fix that I am just missing. I have got 3 columns that consist of a radio button and 2 text columns the issue I am having is that there is no spacing between the 2 text columns but there is between the radio button and the first text field.

I have tried playing around with the row sizes "div class="row-sm-4" but to no luck

```
<div class="col" style="overflow:auto;height:60vh;">
                    <div class="col-sm-12" style="max-height:10%;" ng-repeat="FoundAlises in SearchResults" ng-class="GetClassForSearchResult(FoundAlises)">
                       <div class="row mb-1"> 
                            <div class="col-sm-1 mt-12">
                                <input class="cursorPointer" type="radio" ng-model="$parent.SelectedSearchResult" ng-value="FoundAlises" name="AliasSearchResults" ng-click="OnSearchClicked(FoundAlises)">
                            </div>
                            <div class="row-sm-4">
                                <small class="cursorPointer" ng-click="OnSearchClicked(FoundAlises)">Alias : <small ng-bind="FoundAlises.Alias"></small></small>
                                <small class="cursorPointer" ng-click="OnSearchClicked(FoundAlises)">Tag : <small ng-bind="FoundAlises.Tag"></small></small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

The following is the area where I am having the issue

```
    <div class="row-sm-4">
       <small class="cursorPointer" ng-click="OnSearchClicked(FoundAlises)">Alias : <small ng-bind="FoundAlises.Alias"></small></small>
       <small class="cursorPointer" ng-click="OnSearchClicked(FoundAlises)">Tag : <small ng-bind="FoundAlises.Tag"></small></small>
    </div>
```

I expect the output to be all on one line and have equal spacing between all 3 columns. One thing to note but not sure if this will have any impact is results that are displayed can be different lengths of text. I was hoping that in these cases all of the text in the same column would be inline  eg all of the 'Alias :' labels  would be in line in 1 column and all of the 'Tag :' labels would be inline in the next column

Expected output

```
|Radio Button|       Alias: **********       Tag:*******  
|Radio Button|       Alias: ************     Tag:******* 
|Radio Button|       Alias: *******          Tag:**********
```

Current Output

```
|Radio Button|       Alias: **********       Tag:*******  
|Radio Button|       Alias: ************       Tag:******* 
|Radio Button|       Alias: *******       Tag:**********
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="col" style="overflow:auto;height:60vh;">
  <div class="col-sm-12" style="max-height:10%;" ng-repeat="FoundAlises in SearchResults" ng-class="GetClassForSearchResult(FoundAlises)">
     <div class="row mb-1"> 
          <div class="col-sm-1">
              <input class="cursorPointer" type="radio" ng-model="$parent.SelectedSearchResult" ng-value="FoundAlises" name="AliasSearchResults" ng-click="OnSearchClicked(FoundAlises)">
            </div>
          <div class="col-sm-1">
              <small class="cursorPointer" ng-click="OnSearchClicked(FoundAlises)">Alias : <small ng-bind="FoundAlises.Alias"></small></small>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-1">
            <small class="cursorPointer" ng-click="OnSearchClicked(FoundAlises)">Tag : <small ng-bind="FoundAlises.Tag"></small></small>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This might helps you !

Comment: This worked perfectly just had to modify it slight to get my desired spacing `<small class="cursorPointer pl-lg-5 pr-lg-5"` as well as change the `div class="col-sm-1">` to be `div class="col-sm-4">` to make make it all look neat. Perfect thanks so much

Comment: Anytime !, I'm glad that It worked for you. Happy to help

Answer (score 0):

I've made some changes to your code using bootstrap and inline styles by declaring element width as a percentage and using `display: inline-block;` to keep the rows on the same line, like so:

```
<div class="col" style="overflow:auto;height:60vh;">
  <div class="col-sm-12" style="max-height:10%;" ng-repeat="FoundAlises in SearchResults"
    ng-class="GetClassForSearchResult(FoundAlises)">
    <div class="row mb-1">
      <input style="width: 30%; display: inline-block;" class="cursorPointer align-text-top p-1 m-3"
        type="radio" ng-model="$parent.SelectedSearchResult" ng-value="FoundAlises" name="AliasSearchResults"
        ng-click="OnSearchClicked(FoundAlises)">
      <small style="width: 30%; display: inline-block;" class="cursorPointer align-text-top p-1"
        ng-click="OnSearchClicked(FoundAlises)">Alias : <small ng-bind="FoundAlises.Alias"></small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit
        amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
        minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
        cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</small>
      <small style="width: 30%; float: right;" class="cursorPointer align-text-top p-1"
        ng-click="OnSearchClicked(FoundAlises)">Tag : <small ng-bind="FoundAlises.Tag"></small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit
        amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</small>
    </div>

    <div class="row mb-1">
      <input style="width: 30%; display: inline-block;" class="cursorPointer align-text-top p-1 m-3"
        type="radio" ng-model="$parent.SelectedSearchResult" ng-value="FoundAlises" name="AliasSearchResults"
        ng-click="OnSearchClicked(FoundAlises)">
      <small style="width: 30%; display: inline-block;" class="cursorPointer align-text-top p-1"
        ng-click="OnSearchClicked(FoundAlises)">Alias : <small ng-bind="FoundAlises.Alias"></small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit
        amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
        minim veniam.</small>
      <small style="width: 30%; float: right;" class="cursorPointer align-text-top p-1"
        ng-click="OnSearchClicked(FoundAlises)">Tag : <small ng-bind="FoundAlises.Tag"></small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit
        amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</small>
    </div>

    <div class="row mb-1">
      <input style="width: 30%; display: inline-block;" class="cursorPointer align-text-top p-1 m-3"
        type="radio" ng-model="$parent.SelectedSearchResult" ng-value="FoundAlises" name="AliasSearchResults"
        ng-click="OnSearchClicked(FoundAlises)">
      <small style="width: 30%; display: inline-block;" class="cursorPointer align-text-top p-1"
        ng-click="OnSearchClicked(FoundAlises)">Alias : <small ng-bind="FoundAlises.Alias"></small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit
        amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</small>
      <small style="width: 30%; float: right;" class="cursorPointer align-text-top p-1"
        ng-click="OnSearchClicked(FoundAlises)">Tag : <small ng-bind="FoundAlises.Tag"></small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit
        amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</small>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Hopefully that helps. Let me know if that wasn't what you are looking for.

Comment: This is very close to what I am looking for the only issue is inline text is not working. I am expecting all of the `Alias : <small ng-bind="FoundAlises.Alias"` to be inline in one column and `Tag : <small ng-bind="FoundAlises.Tag"` to be inline in the next column both of which  may need to be left justified to keep the 'Alias' and 'Tag' labels inline. This issue occurs as the `ng-bind="FoundAlises.Alias"` can be varying in length

Comment: Ok some progress... I'm not sure what you mean by 'inline text is not working' though. What is the desired end result? Do you want Alias: and Tags: as the headers and the text below them in the columns?

Comment: Oh I think I understand what you want now. So basically, you want 3 columns with the check box left justified and the two Alias and Tag columns to take up the remainder of the width of the page and the text will wrap and fill down the columns as the length of the text increases? Do you want Alias: and Tags: to be your header?

Comment: No not quite I want each row to be like `Alias: ng-bind="FoundAlias.Alias"` where `Alias: ` is just normal text and the `ng-bind="FoundAlias.Alias"` is some data returned from a database. This is exactly the same for the Tag section as well. The issue is that  the Alias returned from the database can be varying lengths thus it means that the Tags are not all inline vertically

Comment: Modified the question a little to show kind of show what I am looking for, notice how the tag: all remain inline regardless of how long the Alias is

Comment: Made another change to this answer. Let me know if this is what you were shooting for.